# #include errors detected in Visual Studio Code for WebAssembly

Tags: visual-studio-code, webassembly

I'm using web Visual Studio Code for WebAssembly programming. I'm new to C/C++ and WebAssembly. I got VSCode C/C++ plugin installed and in my first hello world application I get following warning

#### warning:

```
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. IntelliSense features for this translation unit (<path>/first_webassembly/hello.c) will be provided by the Tag Parser.
```

Toolchain: `ecmascript`

#### code:

```
#include <stdio.h> // get the warning in this line

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    printf("Hello World\n");
}
```

Found many solutions with configuring the C/C++ plugin's `includePath` with C/C++ includes, but since it's WebAssembly, Is it still valid to configure with paths of GCC includes?

Comment: [Create a minimal complete verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) What toolchain are you going to use with VSCode? Post your code and detailed error message, including which line you got the warning from.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to add the system include paths.  Instead you would want to add the include paths within your emscripten tree.

From line 1042 of `tools/shared.py` it looks like these are:

```
  c_include_paths = [                                                            
    path_from_root('system', 'include', 'compat'),                               
    path_from_root('system', 'include'),                                         
    path_from_root('system', 'include', 'SSE'),                                  
    path_from_root('system', 'include', 'libc'),                                 
    path_from_root('system', 'lib', 'libc', 'musl', 'arch', 'emscripten'),       
    path_from_root('system', 'local', 'include')                                 
  ]                                                                              

  cxx_include_paths = [                                                          
    path_from_root('system', 'include', 'libcxx'),                               
    path_from_root('system', 'lib', 'libcxxabi', 'include')                      
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

1) First, install **MinGW** from this [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/)

2) From the installation manager, mark `*g++ and gcc*` for installation.

3) After installation, go to the bin folder of **MinGW** and check if there are `g++ and gcc files.` Copy the path of the bin folder (Eg: D:/bin).

4) Right click `This PC -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables`.

5) Select PATH and click `Edit -> New` and paste the copied location (bin folder).

6) Now open `VSCode`, save and run the program to get results.